# Use of third party brands

Tags: ios, swift

I've no idea where I should ask this question, but I'll give it a try here:

How am I allowed to use third-party like Instagram, Facebook, etc?

At the moment I've got a view which includes a button.

It has an icon of Instagram, and in the text, it says "Instagram" with a normal font. The link will lead to a tableview which contains a few Instagram accounts, am I allowed to do like this?

Or how can I use the brand "Instagram" to link to a few instagram profiles?

[image: img]

I've it like this. and if you click on it, the app will open a tableview with different instagram names. and if ur clicking on it, it will open instagram for you. is this allowed?

Comment: Hi can you please elaborate more what you are trying to achieve? A screenshot of code and a short video of what you have already implemented would also help understand your problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question and not about programming.

Comment: @nishithSingh check my update

Answer (score 0):

Third party services with open API like Instagram and Facebook got a website for developers with a detailed description of how to use their services and company's policy. This information is frequently updated, so only official documentation can be a source of truth.
There are a couple of those websites for example:

[Instagram policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)

[Facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy)

Comment: can't really find anything about this.. check my update

Comment: @PrezyProgramming here are detailed guidelines about using Instagram assets and brand https://en.instagram-brand.com/

Comment: @nadein Still hard to understand how they mean.. I’m so confused haha